# writing json using rapid json library removes all indention

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I am using rapid json https://rapidjson.org/ for reading a json file and writing it to another one using a cpp on windows application using visual studio 2017.

File Reading Code

```
FILE* fp = fopen(inputJson, "rb"); // non-Windows use "r" 
char readBuffer[65536];
FileReadStream is(fp, readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer));
Document d;
d.ParseStream(is);
fclose(fp);

std::string json_str(readBuffer);
```

File Writing Code

```
FILE* fp2 = fopen(outputJson, "wb"); // non-Windows use "w" 
char writeBuffer[65536];
FileWriteStream os(fp2, writeBuffer, sizeof(writeBuffer));
Writer<FileWriteStream> writer(os);
d.Accept(writer);
fclose(fp2);
```

But in the destination file the indention is all lost.

Source file

```
{
    "name" : "test_rapid",
    "rect_obj": 
    [
        {   "name": "high school mathematics",
            "price": 12,
            "fg_color": 
            {
                "input_type": "val_map_c",
                "input": 
                {   
                    "measname": "MetaData_eOrigin_c",
                    "values":  [0],
                    "mapping": ["white"],
                    "out_of_range" : "white"
                }
            }
        },
```

In destination file the indentions is lost

```
{"name":"test_rapid","rect_obj":[{"name":"high school mathematics","price":12,"fg_color":{"input_type":"val_map_c","input":{
```

How to maintain the indention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep the indentation, you need to use `PrettyWriter` instead of `Writer`:

```
FILE* fp2 = fopen(outputJson, "wb"); 
char writeBuffer[65536];
FileWriteStream os(fp2, writeBuffer, sizeof(writeBuffer));
PrettyWriter<FileWriteStream> writer(os);
writer.SetIndent(' ', 4);  // indent with 4 spaces
d.Accept(writer);
fclose(fp2);
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin for the suggestion. But it looks here we are manually adding the indention using SetIndent. It is not directly taking it as read from the source file. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. RapidJSON does not automatically maintain or replicate indentation from the source file. If you need to preserve the exact same indentation style from the source, you might have to implement custom logic or look for another library that offers this feature. But why would you need that really for?

Comment: Thanks I tried the indention. Its working. Thank you very much. I need the indention to maintain the readibility. Reading without indention in one line is not possible right.